# Can I still get my degree when my tier 4 visa extension application refused?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, student-visa

I am currently a 5th year university student in the UK, and as you can see from the date, it's quite close to graduation and degree awarding time.

My situation is really complex and I will try to explain it well. When I first applied to my university, it was a 4-year program and hence I got a 4-year tier 4 visa for this. And after second year, I changed my program to a 5-year Master's program (I was qualified for this academically).

When it came to the end of my 4 year visa (Summer 2015), I started to apply for an extension with the CAS given by the uni. My first application was refused in August and then I found a nice lawyer to prepare the second application for me. This is all legal since my last visa's expiry date is Sep 2015. But then things went terrible. Due to the home office's "amazing" speed of processing, I had to start my new semester while waiting for the result. The application was later refused in January 2016 and I applied for the 1st administrative review. And then they gave a result based on a totally wrong immigration law hence I applied for a 2nd administrative review. I have kept the university immigration office and international office informed during this period.

And now I'm in my exam period, and I just received the refusal for the application again. There is no more chance for administrative review and I have no legal right to stay in UK. I am really afraid to inform the university about this since they may have to suspend my student status and not award me a degree. But I know that they will eventually find out. And my lawyer is unable to give me any further advice on this case.

### What should I do now?

I am sorry that I used a guest account to ask this question by mistake and now I cannot reply to you guys directly. I will put all the updates here.

@Dan Getz: My Goal is only to get my degree in the end. I have just **finished all my exams**. Hence the only thing that worries me is whether I can get my degree as expected. But whether this can be realized is unsure, the answer I get from multiple departments of the unit are all vague and no one can really answer this. And I am studying at the university of Edinburgh.

@Patricia Shanahan: Yes, my lawyer has informed me of all the necessary law-relevant issues. This also includes the info that I can overstay for around 28 days likely without being punished. And during this period, I have finished my exam (I am not sure if this can be regarded as "complete the program"). As I said in the reply above, the answers from university are all vague.

Comment: "What should I do?" is a hard thing for strangers on the internet to answer for you. Could you explain what your goals are? Is your worry that you will be unable to complete your exams, and thus unable to get your degree? If you pass the exams for your current courses, will that be enough to get your degree? What university are you studying at? I wonder if they could find some way for you to take your exams overseas?

Comment: You say "my lawyer is unable to give me further advice". Can't the lawyer at least advise you on when you need to leave the UK, and the consequences if you don't leave on time? In any case, discussing this with your university seems high priority in case you cannot legally stay in the UK long enough to complete the program.